# Center div inside table cell but align text left

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

I have a wrapper/list `ul` and inside it list items `li`. The `ul` element has `display: table-row;` and the `li` element has `display: table-cell;`. The problem I have now is that I want to center the `li` element inside the list but align the text inside the `li` element on the left.

The code looks like this

```css
.list-wrapper {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.list {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

.item-link {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Text over more lines. Align me left but my parent centered.
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Also centered.
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Here is some text. Align me left.
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Text.
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to align the text **inside** the li, then put the `text-align:center` on the li. I am not sure what you meant by align the items inside the list. Can you share a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: if you are applying the `text-align: center` to the parent element then it will automatically apply to the child element.

Comment: I have edited my question, because my example was not accurate enough. Maybe it is now clear what I need and what I mean. The elememts inside the table are centered, taht is ok. But the text is also aligned 'centered', but I want it to be aligned left.

Comment: Your `.item-link` are inline elements, and you tried to apply `text-align:left` to those. But they are only as wide as their (text) content demands to begin with, so the space on the left and on the right of the text is _zero_. Whether you “align” the text left, right or center in that situation does of course make no difference.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.list {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <a class="item-link">
      Here is some text. Align me left.
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a class="item-link">
      Here is some text. Align me left.
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a class="item-link">
      Here is some text. Align me left.
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <a class="item-link">
      Here is some text. Align me left.
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was not accurate enough. I have updated the code. Maybe it is now clear enough what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that?

```css
.list-wrapper {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.list {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
    display: table-cell;
 padding-right:2%;
 padding-left:2%;
}

.item-link {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Text over more lines. Align me left but my parent centered.
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Also centered.
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Here is some text. Align me left.
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Text.
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was not accurate enough. I have updated the code. Maybe it is now clear enough what I want.

Comment: It is still confusing.

Seems like you want both centered and left alligned.

Comment: Edited my post, added padding to it can you check it? @Cimoe

Answer (score 0):

Not clearly understand what you need to do. Maybe you can try this.

```
.list-item {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was not accurate enough. I have updated the code. Maybe it is now clear enough what I want.

Comment: You can try change css to this: 
.item-link {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```css
.list-wrapper {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.list {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

.item-link {
    text-align: left;
}

.alignLeft{
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
      Here is someText textover more lines. <p class="alignLeft">Align me left but my parent centered.</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
      Here is someAlso textcentered. 
 <p class="alignLeft">Align me left.</p>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
        Here is some text. <p class="alignLeft">Align me left.</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a class="item-link">
      Here is some textText. <p class="alignLeft">Align </p>
 me left.
    </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```